# Pandas caculating rolling functions efficiently

Tags: python, pandas

I need to calculate moving average using `pandas`.

```
ser = pd.Series(np.random.randn(100), 
                index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=100, freq='1min'))

ser.rolling(window=20).mean().tail(5)

[Out]
2000-01-01 01:35:00    0.390383
2000-01-01 01:36:00    0.279308
2000-01-01 01:37:00    0.173532
2000-01-01 01:38:00    0.194097
2000-01-01 01:39:00    0.194743
Freq: T, dtype: float64
```

But after appending a new row like this,

```
new_row = pd.Series([1.0], index=[pd.to_datetime("2000-01-01 01:40:00")])
ser = ser.append(new_row)
```

I have to recalcuate all moving data, like this,

```
ser.rolling(window=20).mean().tail(5)

[Out]
2000-01-01 01:36:00    0.279308
2000-01-01 01:37:00    0.173532
2000-01-01 01:38:00    0.194097
2000-01-01 01:39:00    0.194743
2000-01-01 01:40:00    0.201918
dtype: float64
```

I think I just need calculate last `2000-01-01 01:40:00    0.201918` data, but I can't find pandas api that calculate only last appended row value. Pandas `rolling().mean()` always calculate all series data

This is simple example but in my real project, range is more than 1,000,000 series, and each rolling calculation consumes much time

Is there way to solve this problem in pandas?

Comment: Select last 20 values (for instance with tail(20)) and perform .mean() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Anton vBR wrote in his comment, after you append the row, you can calculate the last value with

```
ser.tail(20).mean
```

which takes time independent of the series length (1000000 in your example).

If you do this operation often, you can calculate it a bit more efficiently. The mean after appending the row is:

- 20 times the mean of the penultimate row
- plus the latest appended value
- minus the value at the 21 last index
- divided by 20

This is more complicated to implement, though.